# ¿Como puedo crear un polyline que el trazo no sea recto y que siga una ruta especifica?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy creando una categoría de rutas de evacuación,en cual tengo en una base de datos de una table con informacion como nombreOrigen,latitudOrigen,longitudeOrigen,nombreDestino,latitudDestino,longitudeDestino,tengo unos datos ya guardados y de esta forma he podido traer esos marcadores y mostrarlos el google maps, he implementado la opción del Polylines que me trazan el punto origen y destino el cual si funcionan correctamente, pero el detalle que las lineas son rectas, el cual yo quiero que tengan una ruta que sigan un camino de como llegar a ese punto, he visto que mencionan algo como la clase Routing pero no he encontrado como implementar esa clase.

**RutasEvacuacion.java**

```
public class RutasEvacuacion_Edomex extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private GoogleMap mMap;

String Url = "https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/listaRutaEvacuaEdomex.php";

private Double latitudeA = 0.00;
private Double longitudeA= 0.00;

private Double latitudeB = 0.00;
private Double longitudeB = 0.00;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rutas_evacuacion__edomex);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.MapsREEdomex);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Permission StrictMode
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String sucess = jsonObject.getString("success");
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("t_rutaevacua_edomex");
                if (sucess.equals("1")){
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        latitudeA = Double.parseDouble(object.get("latitudeOrigen").toString());
                        longitudeA = Double.parseDouble(object.get("longitudeOrigen").toString());

                        latitudeB = Double.parseDouble(object.get("latitudeDestino").toString());
                        longitudeB = Double.parseDouble(object.get("longitudeDestino").toString());

                        if (i == 0){
                            LatLng coordinate1 = new LatLng(latitudeA, longitudeA);
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate1, 10));

                            LatLng coordinate2 = new LatLng(latitudeB, longitudeB);
                            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate2, 10));
                        }
                        String name1 = (String) object.get("nombreOrigen");
                        MarkerOptions marker1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeA, longitudeA)).title(name1)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                        mMap.addMarker(marker1);

                        String name2 = (String) object.get("nombreDestino");
                        MarkerOptions marker2 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeB, longitudeB)).title(name2)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                        mMap.addMarker(marker2);

                        LatLng PuntoOrigen = new LatLng(latitudeA,longitudeA);
                        LatLng PuntoDestino = new LatLng(latitudeB,longitudeB);

                        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .add(PuntoOrigen,PuntoDestino)
                                .width(10)
                                .color(Color.BLUE)
                                .geodesic(true));

                    }
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(RutasEvacuacion_Edomex.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);    
}
}
```

**Rutas de evacuación**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]